# Import tab delimited w/ commas from Excel using SQL 2012 SP

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, import

I'm creating a tab delimited file from Excel to be imported via stored procedure using SQL 2012. I create the file by saving as tab delimited. Some of the values have commas that need to be included. Excel automatically places double quotes around the values with commas. Those values import as nulls. I need the values to import with the commas and without double quotes. I can open the text file and delete all double quotes and the import works fine. Are there any other suggestions? The data is given to me in Excel, so I have to start with that. Is there another process other than saving as tab delimited that would work with the commas? Can I alter the bulk load statement in the stored procedure to not include double quotes?

Here is the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Logins
    (
    [GenericID] numeric(10, 0) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [LoginID] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [EmpType] varchar(50) NOT NULL 
    );
```

Stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUserText]
    WITH EXEC AS CALLER
    AS

   IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#LoginTemp') IS NULL
    BEGIN   

  CREATE TABLE #LoginTemp(LoginID varchar(50),EmpType varchar(50)) 
  BULK INSERT #LoginTemp
       FROM '\\mindlincdb\uploads$\InsertUserText.txt'   
       WITH (ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' 
        ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t' 
       ,FIRSTROW=4)    
        PRINT 'File data copied to Temp table'      
    END

      DECLARE @maxid NUMERIC(10,0)
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      SELECT @maxid = coalesce(MAX(ID), 0)
      FROM   dbo.LOGINS WITH (UPDLOCK)
      INSERT INTO dbo.LOGINS(GenericID,LoginID,EmpType)
      SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + @maxid,
      LoginID, EmpType
      FROM   #LoginTemp;
```

The text file has 3 rows of headings. This is an example of one row of data with a comma (4th row). There are no empty rows in the actual text file. Please ignore extra empty lines in the sample:

```
    Logins    Logins    Logins

    GenericID  LoginID   EmpType 

    GenericID  LoginID   EmpType

    3         pwilson    MA, Resident in Counseling
```

MA, Resident in Counseling needs to import with the comma and without double quotes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what about updating the data after load and replace any leading and trailing double-quotes?

Comment: Flicker, Do you suggest replacing the double quotes in the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. After bulk insert, update the data.

Comment: Thanks. I was just attempting to use replace. I'm getting errors. I'll have to come back to it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after bulk load, update the data using following query:

```
update #LoginTemp
set EmpType = iif(charindex('"', EmpType, 1) = 1, SUBSTRING(EmpType, 2, len(EmpType) - 2), EmpType)
where charindex('"', EmpType, 1) = 1
```

In this query, I assume, if a value is started with `'"'`, it will end with `'"'` too (which is correct assumption)